# Class or Variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, class

If I need to get info from a database, items from an invoice, for instance... should I just get the data into a data table, and store them into variables, or should I create a class?

What's better?

```
MyClass.ItemNumber;
MyClass.Price;
MyClass.InvoiceNumber;
```

or...

```
myItemNumber = (int)dt["itemnumber"];
myPrice = (double)dt["price"];
myInvNum = dt["InvNum"].ToString();
```

Why? If it's something I will never have to use anywhere else, are variables fine, or is it beneficial to create a "Invoice Class"? If I get data, store it in a class instance, is it cached for form posts in .Net? Or is each page recreating the class instance/db call, etc.? How about performance? Please explain concepts. The concepts are the hardest thing for me to grasp... coding--easy. Concepts of .Net--not so easy.

Comment: FYI, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its for immediate use only, class is definitely an unneeded overhead.

Your datatable dt is already an entity in the memory with the data. Variables are enough.

Comment: I would suggest that a Data Transfer Object requires a lot less overhead than an DataTable - which is itself a class.

Comment: @Mike The case here is simply whether using datatable along with a class or using temporary variables with a class and not datatable vs Classes. The datatable is already created. You have misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

The two main reasons for using custom objects (classes) for storing data are type safety, and ease of understanding/maintainability etc in the future. It's a lot easier to understand what `MyInvoice.Customer` is than `dt[0][3].ToString()` or `(string)dt["sCust"]` or some other horrid magic string approach.

[This article from Imar Spaanjaars explains how to use custom objects in ASP.NET development](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1). It's based on ASP.NET 2.0, but is probably the best of its type in terms of communicating the concepts.

Comment: There you go... type safety, and ease of understanding/maintainability, etc, none of which the OP wants at present. Simply said, the class is an unwanted overhead for now.

Comment: The OP goes on to say that the basic concepts are the source of the confusion - the "why". I don't think I misunderstood what Michael is asking about.

Comment: After fooling with my code for a couple days, I think I figured it out. Your input helped. It made it clear once I was able to actually USE it. I like classes, they just seemed like too much overhead, but in the long run, it makes sense to me when to use a class. I take it a class that holds 20 variables isn't much more overhead (if any) than just storing data into 20 variables?

Comment: In a web page, your variables are properties of the current Page object, so they belong to a class anyway. Storage requirements are not a prime driver in the decision between custom objects or datasets in ASP.NET - although datasets/datatables are quite large structures. These things only persist for the few hundred milliseconds it takes the framework to process the code and render the response. After that point, they are all marked for collection and disposal.